# Update an existing post in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

Lets say we have a connected user that access one of his post to replace some existing information in X fields that already exist with some new ones.

How could I manage to update the old ones with the new ones?

Example:

```
custom post type name = recipe
field trying to be updated with new content = $_POST['title']
```

Comment: have you tried `wp_update_post()`?

Comment: that's what im actually testing ! thks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.. I did it in 2 steps and it works perfectly!

```
if(isset ($_POST['new_title']) && $_POST['new_title'] != "")
                            {

                                $post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
                                $id_post = get_the_ID();                
                                $title = get_field('titre');

                                $postInfo = array(
                                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                                    'ID' => $id_post
                                );

                                $id = wp_update_post($postInfo);

                                update_post_meta( $id, 'titre', $_POST['new_title'] );

                                $new_title = $_POST['new_title'];

                                $new_elem = array(
                                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                                    'ID' => $id_post,
                                    'post_title' => $new_title
                                );

                                wp_update_post($new_elem);

                            }
```